# Output a column to a file in R so that only one column appears without index

Tags: r

`write.table` gets the following output from a dataframe, same output as a matrix, and I cant see any relevant options in the documentation:

```
x
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
.....
```

Whereas I want out

```
one
two
three
four
.....
```

How would I go about getting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `row.names=FALSE` and `col.names=FALSE` option

```
write.table(objectname, 'yourfile.txt', row.names=FALSE, 
                          quote=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

If we are using a `matrix` object

```
write(objectname, 'yourfile.txt', ncolumns=1)
```